# How to calculate LOW(b) and HIGH(b) in spritz cryptography

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, rc4

I try to implement spritz cryptography like [this paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS14.pdf) . But I don't know how to calculate LOW(b) and HIGH(b). In paper page 7.

```
low(b) = b mod D
high(b) = b/D

D = square root N
b = D * x+y
```

I don't khow what is x,y. The example LOW(b) and HIGH(b) of N=256 is

```
#define LOW(B)  ((B) & 0xf)
#define HIGH(B) ((B) >> 4)
```

what is LOW(b) and HIGH(b) of N=16.

Comment: 8 is not a square, so `root 8` is not an integer.

Comment: Thank you . I just edit my question little bit.  If N = 16 how to calculate low(b) and high(b).

Comment: $\sqrt{16}=4$ => `low = b mod 4` and `high = b / 4` or if you prefer bitwise operations, `low = b & 3` and `high  = b >> 2`.